# All primes $p$ for which $x^{2} +1$ irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_{p}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, field-theory, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

Let $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ be the field with $p$ elements. Determine all primes $p$ for which $x^{2}+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_{p}$.

Here's what I've got. I think this might be finished but I'm not sure.

If $p=2$ then 1 is a root of $x^{2}+1$ so is reducible over $\mathbb{F}_{p}$. So assume $p>2$. We have $x^{2}+1$ is reducible $\iff$ it has a root $\alpha$ in $\mathbb{F}_{p} \iff \alpha^{2}=-1 \implies \alpha^{4}=1$. Since $\alpha^{3}=-\alpha$ and $-\alpha \neq 1$ when $p>2$ we have $|\alpha| = 4$ in $\mathbb{F}^{\times}_{p}$. Therefore $4$ divides $p-1$ by Lagrange, i.e. $p\equiv 1$ mod $4$ therefore $x^{2}+1$ is irreducible for all primes $p>2$ not congruent to $1$ mod $4$.

> For the converse, evidently this works:
>
> Since $p$ congruent to $1$ mod $4$ we have by Fermat that $p$ is the sum of squares, i.e. $p=a^{2}+b^{2}$. So if $c=(ab)^{-1}$ in $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ then $x^{2}+1=(x+ca^{2})(x+cb^{2})$ so is reducible.

Comment: It is correct.  You have not proved that the polynomial is reducible for all primes $\equiv 1\pmod{4}$. It is.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, you're not missing anything; all of the $\implies$ you wrote down are really $\iff$.

To be more explicit about the other direction: if $p\equiv 3\bmod 4$, then $\mathbb{F}_p^\times$ is a cyclic group of order $p-1\equiv 2\bmod 4$, so that there cannot be an element $\alpha\in\mathbb{F}_p^\times$ of order $4$ by Lagrange's theorem, so that the polynomial $x^2+1$ cannot have roots in $\mathbb{F}_p$, so that the polynomial $x^2+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Comment: I thought most of them would be, but I'm certain that $\alpha^{2}=-1 \implies \alpha^{4} =1$ is not an $\iff$ though.

Comment: This actually repeats the direction the OP did prove, just in contrapositive form.  The "other" other direction would be to show that if $p\equiv1\bmod4$, then $x^2+1$ is reducible over $\mathbb{F}_p$, which is true but not so immediate.

Comment: @ Barry, okay so I proved that if it's reducible p is 1 mod 4 but now I need to prove that if p is 1 mod 4 then it's reducible.

Answer (score 1):

To prove that $p\equiv1 \pmod 4$ implies that $x^2 + 1$ is reducible over $\mathbb{F}_p$, we have by Fermat's two square theorem that $a^2 + b^2 = p$ with $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then

$$a^2 + b^2 = 0 \pmod p \;\iff\; a^2 = -b^2 \pmod p $$ $$\;\iff\; a^2(b^2)^{-1} = -1 \pmod p \;\iff\; -a^2(b^{-1})^2 = 1.$$

So we obtain that $$x^2 + 1 = x^2 -a^2(b^{-1})^2 = (x + ab^{-1})(x - ab^{-1}),$$ hence $x^2 + 1$ is reducible in $\mathbb{F}_p$.